# How to clear only selected row in data-table, vuetify

Tags: vue.js, datatable, vuetify.js, selection

I have a vue app where Im using v-data table with show-select option. I want to clear only selected data using "cancel" button and Im looking for solution how to do it correctly. Already I can clear all data from table onclick.

Example on picture:
I want to clear only selected row(Ice cream sandwich)
[image]

Here is my code:

Table:

```
 <v-data-table
    v-model="selected"
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    :single-select="singleSelect"
    item-key="name"
    show-select
    class="elevation-1"
  >
    <template v-slot:top>
      <v-switch
        v-model="singleSelect"
        label="Single select"
        class="pa-3"
      ></v-switch>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
```

"cancel" button

```
<v-btn class="ma-2" color="primary" @click="cancel"> Cancel </v-btn>
```

script

```
 cancel() {
      
        this.desserts = [];
      
    },
```

Comment: @JayFridge, yes its a good solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Use any unique property (in this example - an id) to filter the row out of your items array.

```
cancel(){
    this.desserts = this.desserts.filter((e)=> {
      return e.id !== this.selected.id;
    });
  }
```

Comment: It doesnt work in this case, unfortunatelly. I havent got any result

Comment: It's an example, if your object's structure doesn't contain a property by the name 'id' use any other unique property, like 'name'.

Comment: in my struture its "text" but when I use this property all data are deleted - selected and unselected :)